# Find all folders containing upper case letters below a certain folder

Tags: powershell, regex

I want to find all folders that contain at least one upper case letter and that are beneath a certain folder.

I played around with this power shell so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
    | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
    | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "^.*?refs\\.*[A-Z]+.*$"}
    | Select-Object FullName
```

But it fails in that it lists ALL folders that contain upper case letters ANYWHERE in their name. I only want subfolders of `refs` to be listed.

Where's my error? When I try the regex in a regex testing engine, it correctly only lists subfolders of `refs`. Apparently the power shell engine works differently?

Comment: Could you provide sample directory names for matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange indeed. It seems that `-Match` operator will not care about case regardless of what is in regex (or maybe there is a different explanation).

Nevertheless, changing `-Match` to `-CMatch` (case-sensitive match) seems to be working for ma sample directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object FullName -CMatch "^.*?refs\\.*[A-Z]+.*$" | select Fullname
```

---

You can also use the `[regex]` type accelerator for greater control.

```
$regex = [regex]"^.*?refs\\.*[A-Z]+.*$"
$match = $regex.Match('C:\Users\user\refs\whatever\test1\test2\test3')
```

Comment: Yeah `cmatch` works perfectly. Thanks for the hint!